# How to get cordova-whitelist-plugin into staging Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, whitelist

**I cannot get the *cordova-whitelist plugin* into the staging map of Xcode via Ionic.** I have tried removing the whitelist plugin, tried adding it back (by installing), yet still nothing at all. `ionic prepare ios` normally solves these issues for me, but the whitelist plugin is still not being added.

What is the best way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer for all those out there facing the same problems because of the *lack of proper documentation*: the `cordova-whitelist-plugin` is not meant to be for iOS, which is the reason why it's not going into staging. Thus: this is not a problem at all, as it's just the way it should work.

Source: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-get-the-cordova-whitelist-plugin-into-staging-in-xcode-via-ionic/97058/2?u=1bjk903